# Unable to connect the html files with angular , issue with controller file coding

Tags: angularjs

Am new to Angular.js and i wrote my first app, but unfortunately, there seems to be a problem in my code, which i could not figure it our, Can someone please help me on this,i have placed code in git

In my application, browser always displays {{title}}, rather values associated with it
web link: "https://github.com/srinivasraomc/AngularJs11"

```
**server.js**
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res)
{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/index.html');
});
app.use( express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

var port = 3000;
app.listen(port, function()
    {
        console.log('running running in port node' +port);
    }
);


addresscontroller.js
function addressctr($scope)
{
    $scope.title = 10;

}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head lang="en">
   <!-- <meta charset="UTF-8"> -->
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
</head>
<body>

index.html 
<div ng-controller="addressctr">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
</div>

<script src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src ="addresscontroller.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

thanks
Srinivas

Comment: Add relevant code here at SO.

Comment: is the code two separate files? or three separate files?

Answer (score 1):

Angular 1.3+ no longer supports controller declaration on the global scope. You need to use `module.controller()` to register the controller.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('addressctr', function($scope) {
    $scope.title = 10;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="addressctr">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I could fix this, Probable was following old tutorials, thanks for quick response

Answer (score 0):

you didn't defined your angular module and some more necessary data is missed in html and js files.please check the below for proper formatting

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('addressctr', function($scope) {
   $scope.title = 10;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
   <script src ="addresscontroller.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="addressctr">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I could fix this, Probable was following old tutorials

Answer (score 0):

you just given ng-app only, not configured your module. Default angular functionality only work.. do this.

```
angular.module('firstApp', [])
  .controller('addressctr', function($scope) {
    $scope.title = "My first Angular App";
  });

<html ng-app="firstApp">
```